# Is there any way to use premake to build a linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, premake

I'm trying to build a kernel module in part of a larger project that uses premake5 to generate the Makefiles. However, there's no documentation on using premake to build a kernel module. Is this possible in premake? I'd like to stay consistent with using Premake in the project, if possible.

Thank you in advance for any insights.

My attempt thus far:

```
project "mymod"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C"
    location "./"
    files { "**.h", "**.c" }

    if _ACTION == "clean" then
        os.rmdir("obj")
    end

    buildcommands {
      "make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules %{cfg.buildcfg}"
   }

   rebuildcommands {
      "make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules %{cfg.buildcfg} rebuild"
   }

   cleancommands {
      "make clean %{cfg.buildcfg}"
   }

    buildoptions{ "-Wno-unused-value", "-Wno-sign-compare", 
        "-Wno-unused-parameter", "-Wno-unused-function",
        "-Wno-missing-field-initializers"}


    configuration {"Release"}
        defines { "NDEBUG" }
        flags { "Optimize", "ExtraWarnings", "FatalWarnings", "FloatStrict", "EnableSSE2" }
```

What follows is an example of a working Makefile for building a kernel module. Granted, it's short and probably doesn't seem worth the trouble of using Premake, but that's because it is missing several object files from the listing, which currently have to be entered manually.

```
# Note that multiple KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS Entries are space-separated
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=$(ETHERCAT_TOPDIR)/Module.symvers \
    $(HOME_DIR)/shmdrv/Module.symvers \

# the output kernel module
obj-m := corert.o

# the object files used

corert-objs := ctsrt_main.o globals.o ProcessMain.o \
    CtsSharedData.o ProcessData.o   \
    ProcessSdo.o ProcessSimulate.o \
    FsmWrite.o


ETHERCAT_TOPDIR = /usr/local/src/ethercat
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -I$(ETHERCAT_TOPDIR)/include -ffast-math -mhard-float

all:


    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) \
        modules 

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: How would you build a Linux kernel module without Premake? What isn't working when you add Premake?

Comment: I added an example to the original post. Thanks!